# Why does more acetic acid require more sodium hydroxide in order to be neutralized

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration

I was recently titrating sodium hydroxide against vinegar and based off my results i realised that the vinegars with a higher concentration  of acetic acid required more sodium hydroxide in order to be neutralized. Why is this so? Does this happen for all acids regardless of pH?

Comment: Sounds quite obvious : more acetic acid needs more NaOH to be neutralised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A higher concentration of acetic acid means more molecules (or moles) of acetic acid in the same volume that you used. So, it's pretty clear that you need to use more $\ce{NaOH}$ to neutralize the acetic acid.

1 mol of acetic acid reacts completely with 1 mol of sodium hydroxide.
$$\ce{CH3COOH + NaOH -> CH3COONa + H2O}$$

So obviously, increasing the number of moles of acetic acid (i.e. increasing the concentration) will necessitate a corresponding increase in the number of moles of $\ce{NaOH}$ (i.e. by using more $\ce{NaOH}$).

And yes, this should happen for all other acids too.